# Number conversion functionality

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, keypad, mikroc

I have been trying to find some code to assist me with writing the program for my final project, but having troubles finding samples that are relevant enough to get me going.

The program I wish to write will convert an input number from either `Decimal`, `Binary` or `Hex`, and display the value in it's converted form/s.

I have found similar code for the conversion program which I understand the modulus process, but I'm having troubles getting my head around the interfacing process and how to get the input values from the keypad stored as a single variable, to then be used in the conversion process.

I am using PIC16F877A and MikroC for the compiler program and the project is using a 4x4 Keypad and 2x16 LCD for display.

Any feedback and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For this sort of question, it's really useful if you provide some code with a `// MAGIC GOES HERE` comment or such.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put together some example code to give a better understanding of what I'm asking!